# Clip-path is not working. Did I miss something?

Tags: css, reactjs, svg, react-functional-component, clip-path

I'm trying to use `clip-path` in CSS but it's not working. I've watched plenty tutorials by now and it seems simple, but it's just not working and doesn't appear to be trying to work. I should also mention I'm using React--which, whenever I've run into issues recently, it's caused by React.

To my own knowledge, I've done everything I'm supposed to. The SVG is loaded in the DOM as a `clipPath` tag, with a unique ID and I reference that ID in the CSS.

Please help. Thanks.

SVG Blob (imported in the DOM via `import {ReactComponent as LIST_ICON} from ...`:

```
<svg className="list-icon" viewBox="0 0 64 48">
      <path d="M12.343,2V10.343c0,1.104-.896,2-2,2H2c-1.105,0-2-.896-2-2V2C0,.896,.895,0,2,0H10.343c1.104,0,2,.896,2,2Zm-2,15.829H2c-1.105,0-2,.896-2,2v8.343c0,1.104,.895,2,2,2H10.343c1.104,0,2-.896,2-2v-8.343c0-1.104-.896-2-2-2Zm0,17.829H2c-1.105,0-2,.896-2,2v8.343c0,1.105,.895,2,2,2H10.343c1.104,0,2-.895,2-2v-8.343c0-1.104-.896-2-2-2ZM62,0H19.828c-1.104,0-2,.896-2,2V10.343c0,1.104,.896,2,2,2H62c1.104,0,2-.896,2-2V2c0-1.104-.896-2-2-2Zm0,17.829H19.828c-1.104,0-2,.896-2,2v8.343c0,1.104,.896,2,2,2H62c1.104,0,2-.896,2-2v-8.343c0-1.104-.896-2-2-2Zm0,17.829H19.828c-1.104,0-2,.896-2,2v8.343c0,1.105,.896,2,2,2H62c1.104,0,2-.895,2-2v-8.343c0-1.104-.896-2-2-2Z" />
      <symbol id="list-icon" viewBox="0 0 64 48">
        <path d="M12.343,2V10.343c0,1.104-.896,2-2,2H2c-1.105,0-2-.896-2-2V2C0,.896,.895,0,2,0H10.343c1.104,0,2,.896,2,2Zm-2,15.829H2c-1.105,0-2,.896-2,2v8.343c0,1.104,.895,2,2,2H10.343c1.104,0,2-.896,2-2v-8.343c0-1.104-.896-2-2-2Zm0,17.829H2c-1.105,0-2,.896-2,2v8.343c0,1.105,.895,2,2,2H10.343c1.104,0,2-.895,2-2v-8.343c0-1.104-.896-2-2-2ZM62,0H19.828c-1.104,0-2,.896-2,2V10.343c0,1.104,.896,2,2,2H62c1.104,0,2-.896,2-2V2c0-1.104-.896-2-2-2Zm0,17.829H19.828c-1.104,0-2,.896-2,2v8.343c0,1.104,.896,2,2,2H62c1.104,0,2-.896,2-2v-8.343c0-1.104-.896-2-2-2Zm0,17.829H19.828c-1.104,0-2,.896-2,2v8.343c0,1.105,.896,2,2,2H62c1.104,0,2-.895,2-2v-8.343c0-1.104-.896-2-2-2Z" />
      </symbol>
      <defs>
        <clipPath id="list-icon-clip" clipPathUnits="objectBoundingBox">
          <path d="M12.343,2V10.343c0,1.104-.896,2-2,2H2c-1.105,0-2-.896-2-2V2C0,.896,.895,0,2,0H10.343c1.104,0,2,.896,2,2Zm-2,15.829H2c-1.105,0-2,.896-2,2v8.343c0,1.104,.895,2,2,2H10.343c1.104,0,2-.896,2-2v-8.343c0-1.104-.896-2-2-2Zm0,17.829H2c-1.105,0-2,.896-2,2v8.343c0,1.105,.895,2,2,2H10.343c1.104,0,2-.895,2-2v-8.343c0-1.104-.896-2-2-2ZM62,0H19.828c-1.104,0-2,.896-2,2V10.343c0,1.104,.896,2,2,2H62c1.104,0,2-.896,2-2V2c0-1.104-.896-2-2-2Zm0,17.829H19.828c-1.104,0-2,.896-2,2v8.343c0,1.104,.896,2,2,2H62c1.104,0,2-.896,2-2v-8.343c0-1.104-.896-2-2-2Zm0,17.829H19.828c-1.104,0-2,.896-2,2v8.343c0,1.105,.896,2,2,2H62c1.104,0,2-.895,2-2v-8.343c0-1.104-.896-2-2-2Z" />
        </clipPath>
      </defs>
    </svg>
```

More specifically:

```
<defs>
    <clipPath id="list-icon-clip" clipPathUnits="objectBoundingBox">
      <path d="M12.343,2V10.343c0,1.104-.896,2-2,2H2c-1.105,0-2-.896-2-2V2C0,.896,.895,0,2,0H10.343c1.104,0,2,.896,2,2Zm-2,15.829H2c-1.105,0-2,.896-2,2v8.343c0,1.104,.895,2,2,2H10.343c1.104,0,2-.896,2-2v-8.343c0-1.104-.896-2-2-2Zm0,17.829H2c-1.105,0-2,.896-2,2v8.343c0,1.105,.895,2,2,2H10.343c1.104,0,2-.895,2-2v-8.343c0-1.104-.896-2-2-2ZM62,0H19.828c-1.104,0-2,.896-2,2V10.343c0,1.104,.896,2,2,2H62c1.104,0,2-.896,2-2V2c0-1.104-.896-2-2-2Zm0,17.829H19.828c-1.104,0-2,.896-2,2v8.343c0,1.104,.896,2,2,2H62c1.104,0,2-.896,2-2v-8.343c0-1.104-.896-2-2-2Zm0,17.829H19.828c-1.104,0-2,.896-2,2v8.343c0,1.105,.896,2,2,2H62c1.104,0,2-.895,2-2v-8.343c0-1.104-.896-2-2-2Z" />
    </clipPath>
  </defs>
```

JSX (HTML):

```
<button className="hint-cache-toggle" onClick={e => e.preventDefault()}>
```

CSS:

```
#answer-input .hint-cache-toggle {
  position: absolute;
  inset: auto 0 0 auto;
  border: none;
  width: 64px;
  height: 48px;
  clip-path: url("#list-icon-clip");
  /* -webkit-clip-path: url("#list-icon-clip"); */
  background-color: black;
}
```

Comment: objectBoundingBox units should be in the range [0..1] Your path values look too large.

Comment: @RobertLongson removing objectBoundingBox altogether doesn't resolve the issue either.

Comment: Be more specific. What isn't resolved? For me, if I make a static web page fragment out of your code, everything looks like it is working.

Comment: @ccprog The element I’m trying to clip remains un-clipped, on my end.

Comment: Doo you see the clipped button bottom-right? https://codepen.io/ccprog/pen/MWXYvBV

Comment: I see it. But I can't replicate it.

Comment: I separated the clipPath element entirely and it worked. But I'm confused as to why it wouldn't work in the defs tag within a parent SVG

Comment: EDIT: it does work when it's nested (SVG > defs > clipPath). I copied the content of the SVG file into the footer and it works. So the issue must be in importing it.